# How to generate a N*D random matrix with columns of unit length?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, random

Is it possible to generate a N*D random matrix with columns of unit length?

If not, I also think it is possible of generating a N*D random matrix and, after that, normalizing it in order to have columns of unit length.

Is this last case, how is this possible mathematically?

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: It's certainly 'possible.' What constraints do you have? How do you want the elements to be distributed? And, what's wrong with what you say, i.e., generating a totally random matrix (with elements between what and what? complex, real, rational or other), and then normalizing as you say?

Comment: @NarutSereewattanawoot, I am coding it in objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the column vectors to be uniformly distributed on the unit sphere, you may first generate an $N\times D$ rectangular array of standard normal pseudorandom numbers, and then normalise the length of each column vector.

Comment: And how is that normalization done?

Comment: Here, "normalisation" means to divide each column entrywise by its length, so that it is scaled to length $1$.

Comment: I have been able to complete the whole process. However, the norm does not match one.

Comment: @dwbrito Could you tell me more details? After division, the length should be equal to $1$. In fact, if $v\neq0$, it is necessarily true that $\left\|\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\|=1$.

Comment: @user551, my process is (now just doing it for a vector - with real samples): 
- Generate a vector of pseudo random numbers [0.767554, 1.10478, 1.0696]
- Normalize the vector, by diving each column by its length [0.255851, 0.36826, 0.356532]

However, computing the norm sqrt(0.255851^2 + 0.36826^2 + 0.356532^2) = 0.57287 != 1

Comment: @dwbrito The length of a vector means its norm (as you can see in my previous comment, by "the length should be equal to $1$", I meant $\left\|\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\|$, i.e. the norm of the vector $v/\|v\|$ is equal to $1$). So you should divide your vector by $\sqrt{0.767554^2+1.10478^2+1.0696^2}\approx 1.7186$. Also, you should generate the pseudorandom numbers from a standard normal distribution. Your vector $[0.767554, 1.10478, 1.0696]$ indicates that you might be generating only uniform pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: I have finally made it. I've corrected the numbers generation and also the normalisation. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: if, by any chance, you are interested, this was the final implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614074/how-to-generate-a-random-ny-matrix-with-columns-of-unit-length